# Android Firebase - how to get child node data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have node of "genresComments" that saves comments of each user to for each video id. It goes like that Genre -> video ID -> user ID:Data.
What im trying to get is all the user's id and their data (The data i mean:comment,profilePicture,username).

*thats the query that should point to that data*

```
      Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Params.GENRESCOMMENTS).child(genre).child(videoID);
```

But i'm sure that it points only on the "users id" and not bringing me the inside data that i need.

My question is how do i get for each "video id" all his "user id" and his data (comment,profilePicture,username).

**EDIT**

```
     @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    videoID = getArguments().getString(Params.VIDEOID);
    genre = getArguments().getString(Params.GENRE);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if(videoID != null){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Params.GENRESCOMMENTS).child(genre).child(videoID);
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comment>().setQuery(query,Comment.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment,CommentsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(CommentsViewHolder holder, int position, Comment model) {
                    holder.userName.setText(model.getUserName());
                    holder.comment.setText(model.getComment());
                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(model.getUserProfile()).into(holder.userProfile);
            }

            @Override
            public  CommentsViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_item,parent,false);
                return new CommentsViewHolder(view) ;
            }
        };

    }
    if(adapter != null) {
        rvComments.setAdapter(adapter);
        rvComments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }

}
```

*I use this query for recycler view*

[image]

Comment: When you load a node from the Firebase Realtime Database, the `DataSnapshot` contains all data under that node too. If you're having a hard time accessin the data in that snapshot, please share the code of how you're trying (so what you do inside `onDataChange` or `onChild...`).

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Do like below code (it may get errors): learn about event listener first

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Params.GENRESCOMMENTS).child(genre).child(videoID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(Datasnapshot snap){

  for(DataSnapshot s:snap.getChildren()){
         Comment c=s.getValue(Comment.class);
         //c.getPRofilePic  c.getComment();
    }
});


class Comment {
private String comment;
private String profilePic;
private String username;

//getter setter


}
```

Comment: This is nice but not helping for my needs. I try to build query for the recyclerview and not use "addValueEventListener" for getting the data